# Convert Variable Value to Array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I create a ajax call for fetching data from database using datatables and jquery which are absolutely working fine, i am getting all the value in the console.log in jQuery but i can't find a solution to get those value from console.log and put in my html  using by giving it's Id

These values are the sum of 4 different columns respectively
i.e.

pageTotal is my variable is showing 9 different values which is totally fine when i am consoling it, i am getting the values, i just want to get these 9 different values to store in array so that i can do further calculation depending on these values by using it's index.

below is the image, about how i am getting the value in console form when i am consoling it i.e. console.log(pageTotal);

need help to get these values and store in array for further calculations.

[image]

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api();
        nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;

        // console.log(nb_cols);

        var j = 5;

        while(j < nb_cols){
          var pageTotal = api
                .column( j, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return Number(a) + Number(b);
                }, 0 );

            console.log(pageTotal);

          // Update footer
          $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
          j++;
        } 
      }
```

Comment: `array.push(pageTotal)`

Comment: no! when i am doing this, i shows me in the console 
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the values by defining the array at the start:

```
var arrPageTotal = [];
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
     var api = this.api();
     nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;

     // console.log(nb_cols);

     var j = 5;

     while(j < nb_cols){
         var pageTotal = api
             .column( j, { page: 'current'} )
             .data()
             .reduce( function (a, b) {
                 return Number(a) + Number(b);
             }, 0 );

        console.log(pageTotal);
        arrPageTotal.push(pageTotal) //Adds the value to the list
        // Update footer
        $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
        j++;
    } 
}
//You can use arrPageTotal
```

Comment: it didn't help it! when i am doing this, it shows me in the console 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4, instead of this i want in console like i showed in the my image above in array, kindly need help in this

Comment: @AbdulRafay Calling `arrPageTotal.push()` can't change the value of `pageTotal` that was logged.

Comment: @Barmar sir as i show in my image above that, these values are coming on console against variable, i.e. pageTotal   but when i am doing to push in array as you said, it give me the number like above content

Comment: That's not possible, you must be doing something wrong.